# cannot open output file test: Is a directory collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: permissions, files

I want to compile the program using these command:gcc -o test test.c,then it displays these:

```
yangbin@yangbin-desktop:~/桌面$ gcc -o test test.c
/usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file test: Is a directory
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I cannot understand why,please give me a hand to solve it!
I am a freshman.

```
/*****test.c*********/
#include
int main(void)
{
        int input=0;
        printf("enter an integer:");
        scanf("%d",&input);
        printf("Twice the number you supplied is %d\n",2*input);
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a directory named "test" at the path you are trying to compile from, either rename the directory or change the output filename (-o somethingelse) . Optionally (and the best option) is to move test.c to it's own directory and compile from there.

Comment: I have try following what you said,but ...you know ,the problem still alive!

Answer (score 1):

At the shell prompt you issued the gcc command at, try "cd test".  If it doesn't error and you get into a subdirectory called test, then the problem is exactly what the error message says.  To fix that, try changing the "test" after the "-o" to some other name.